# Ms acces how to make a matrix with same row and clomnum value

Tags: ms-access, matrix, combinations

So I want to make an overview of the combinations of teachers there are for the assessments of students. Teachers are divided in three groups and I want to know who worked together and how many times this is from different groups.

The data is built in the following way:

Student - Teacher 1 - Teacher 2/

Chris - Teacher A - Teacher B/

John - Teacher B - Teacher D/

Marie - Teacher D - Teacher A/

and a different table where the teacher information is given including to which group they belong.

When you make a 'normal' matrix, you get all the data double. And you only need half of the matrix.

So I tried making an extra column of the combinations, with teacher 1 and 2 in one column (in alphabetical order so it is always A-B and never B-A). But now I can only make a table and I would prefer a matrix.

In Excel I know how to do it, Excel has an easy way to split a value on the space. Than I have all the combinations in alphabetical order over two columns, and I can make a pivot table. By making a second dummy employee table I can group the row and the column values.
But how can I do the same in Access?

Example of what I want
[image: Example of what I want]

Because of the knowledge of my colleagues I should stay within MS Access.
Can someone help me? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Seems like a job for Excel only.

Comment: Edit question to show sample data as text tables.